# `begin` block vs parentheses: just a matter of style?

Tags: ruby

Consider the following two Ruby snippets:

```
def foo
  @foo ||= begin
    get_the_foo
  end
end
```

vs

```
def foo
  @foo ||= (
    get_the_foo
   )
end
```

The results are the same. Personally, I prefer the second, because `begin` makes me expect exception handling.

Is there any difference in these besides style? Eg, performance, scope, memory, etc?

My guess would be that `begin` is 'heavier' because it can do more.

Comment: I think the difference would be ignorable, if any.

Comment: I benchmarked both and got same results for both so I guess is that they are the same internally.

Comment: I wouldn't do either - I'd just do `@foo ||= get_the_foo`.

Comment: @sevenseacat It could require multiple steps, e.g., `@foo ||= (prepare_to_get_it; get_the_foo)`. In this case with 1 expression you are right, of course.

Comment: I tried Benchmarking (I took out the memoization, added several lines in each)... the timings over 3_000_000 iterations were almost identical, and neither method was consistently faster than the other. And neither creates a local scope. And a method can do exception handling without a begin statement so I don't think there's additional overhead added for that. Neat question!

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think there's a significant difference between the two besides style, I guess the real question should be "Is it a good idea use multiline computations to produce a return value to an inline expression?".

The Ruby's conditional assignment shortcut is already poorly readable. I'm positive that, if you need more than one step to get a value, you should extract them to a method and simply call `@foo ||= method_to_get_the_foo`.